# URL mapping between 2 domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-mapping

We have an online service with 3 customers: Autoparts, CarExamples and Cars & More. This is the url structure:

- example.com/autoparts
- example.com/carexamples
- example.com/carsandmore

One of the customers (CarExamples) wants to use their own domain (carexamples.com), but it has to load the content of example.com/carexamples, of course always using the original domain.

That means that:

- carexamples.com should load example.com/carexamples
- carexamples.com/about should load example.com/carexamples/about
- carexamples.com/categories/trucks?p=1 should load example.com/carexamples/categories/trucks?p=1

We are using a LAMP environment (PHP v5.6). The domain example.com is located in `/www/example/html` in our server.

The current status of this issue is:

1. Create an A record in the domain's DNS manager console that points to the same server where example.com is being hosted.
2. Add a virtual host for the custom domain

   ```
   <VirtualHost servername:80>
       ServerName carexamples.com
       ServerAlias www.carexamples.com
       DocumentRoot /www/example/html
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

But this would just load the same content of example.com when opening carexamples.com

It is worth noting that `/www/example/html/carexamples` is not a directory, it is a rewrite from `/www/example/html/store.php?store=carexamples`

Shopify does something similar: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/domains/add-a-domain/using-existing-domains/connecting-domains#set-up-your-existing-domain-to-connect-to-shopify maybe that could help as a reference to this issue.

These are the existing rewrite rules in the .htaccess file:

```
# stores
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})$ /store.php?store=$1 [QSA,L]

# stores > categories
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,50})$ /store.cat.php?store=$1&cat=$2 [QSA,L]

# stores > categories > items
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,50})/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,100})$ /store.cat.php?store=$1&cat=$2&id_item=$3&item=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You said `It is worth noting that /www/example/html/carexamples is not a directory, it is a rewrite from /www/example/html/store.php?store=carexamples`. What would be the target when the url is `example.com/carexamples/categories/trucks?p=1` ?

Comment: @JustinIurman `/www/example/html/carexamples/categories/trucks?p=1` is loaded from `/www/example/html/category.php?store=carexamples&cat=trucks&p=1`

Comment: What about the other pages then ? It looks like it lacks some needed info, in order to build a more-or-less generic rule. You said earlier that `/carexamples/*` was a rewrite of `/store.php?store=carexamples`, and now you tell me that `/carexamples/categories/*` is a rewrite of `/category.php?store=carexamples&cat=*` (note `category.php` instead of `store.php`). Is it a mistake or... ? Could you provide a complete scheme of urls to be rewritten (new format -> old format) ?

Comment: Can you show your existing rewrite rules?

Comment: @anubhava i just added them to the original post

Comment: As per first requirement i.e. `carexamples.com should load example.com/carexamples`. How do you plan to support `autoparts` and `carsandmore` later?

Comment: @anubhava when they configure their domains, `autoparts.com` should load `example.com/autoparts`,  `carsandmore.com` should load `example.com/carsandmore`

Answer (score 1):

Have your rules like this in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# per domain rewrite
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?example\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)[^:]*:(?!/\1/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# stores
RewriteRule ^([\w-]{2,50})/?$ store.php?store=$1 [QSA,L]

# stores > categories
RewriteRule ^([\w-]{2,50})/([\w-]{1,50})/?$ store.cat.php?store=$1&cat=$2 [QSA,L]

# stores > categories > items
RewriteRule ^([\w-]{2,50})/([\w-]{1,50})/(\d+)/([\w-]{1,100})/?$ store.cat.php?store=$1&cat=$2&id_item=$3&item=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This might seem a good idea for 3 domains, but this list could expand up to hundreds of domains. Wouldn't that .htaccess processing be to expensive cpu-wise in the long run?

Comment: ok I understand what you're saying. I'm in a meeting now but afterwards I will try to make this rule dynamic.

Comment: I see where your solution is going, it could work, but your rules are throwing a "Internal Server Error" (without detail)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your post correctly (correct me or clarify if this isn't what you're looking for)

You need a separated vHost for each entry ..  You're looking at the wrong directory  -- This is an example --  Though it should be self explanatory .. Just add  `/carexamples` to the `DocumentRoot`

```
<VirtualHost servername:80>
    ServerName carexamples.com
    ServerAlias www.carexamples.com
    DocumentRoot /www/example/html/carexamples
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i should clarify that `/www/example/html/carexamples` is not a directory, it is a rewrite from `/www/example/html/store.php?store=carexamples` so I don't think your solution would actually work.

Comment: It could be worth looking into a `php` only solution looking at the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` -- Depending on your environment an `.htaccess` rule will just cause a *Too many Redirects* issue.

Comment: i'll give it a try, don't know what will happen when making POST requests - that would be my main concern.